# How to store images in DB from DataGridView - C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have DataGridView control in my form and the last column type is image.

How I can let the user select image in DataGridView and save it in the DB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the image itself in the DB bt in the filesystem and in tue DB store the images name only. This is a better option than stuffing data into DB blobs.

Comment: Because a filesystem has been designed to, well, store files. You can access them directly without converting bytes forth and back from and to blobs. If you're dealing with a web application and your DB and webserver run on different machines, all your images have to travel from the DB machin over the network to the webserver to be served from there. Wasted traffic. If you just have some small images, go stuff them in the DB. There are various arguments - pro and contra.

Answer (score 0):

You can store arbitrary files in a SQL Server database by using a field with type `BLOB` ("Binary Large OBject"). Create a column of this type in your table, then you can load file data into it by referencing a file on the hard drive, probably using a stored procedure

There are quite a few articles on using BLOBS; here is a good-looking tutorial: [Part one](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3719221/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server.htm), [part two](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3724556/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server-Part-2.htm).

Here is some sample code from that article that is specifically adding a BLOB value from a file:

```
INSERT INTO BLOBTest
(BLOBName, BLOBData)
SELECT 'First test file', 
    BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(
        Bulk 'C:\temp\nextup.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

Whether or not you *should* do this is an entirely different question.